# Wrong starting row of the resulting table while calculating annualized return

Tags: r

I have a sample data that looks like the following.

```
ID  Return
1   NA
2   0
3   0.0092
4   -0.00262
5   0
6   0.066976
7   0
8   0
9   0.082
10  0
11  0
12  0.090683
13  0
14  0
15  0.037367
16  -0.0053
17  0
18  0.025207
```

The table is monthly return. I want to convert it to annual return. My code is:

```
df2 <- rollapply(df2 + 1, 12, prod, fill = NA) -1
```

The result is below:

```
1   NA
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
6   NA
7   0.26741
8   0.26741
9   0.302784
10  0.29928
11  0.29928
12  0.248417
13  0.248417
14  0.248417
15  0.141164
16  0.141164
17  0.141164
18  0.144608
```

I would expect the resulting table start from row 13 because it needs the first 12 months to calculate the annual return, but why does it start from row 7?

Comment: The default of the `align` argument of `rollapply` is `center`, so this makes sense. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-1/topics/rollapply

Comment: I think you're looking for `align = 'right'`, assuming that you're trying to force that behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the "align" parameter in the rollapply function, the window is centered meaning that the output in row 7 is based on the inputs from rows 1 through 12.

To get the result you're looking for, you should set the "align" argument to "right" I think.

Comment: See link provided by user www in the comment to your original question.